# Android Studio is adding me android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS on my manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, manifest-merging

When i compile my app for release, a new permission called USE_CREDENTIALS is being added to my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

Why? What is this permission? **i can't find any official info about it** on android developers guide!

Thanks

Comment: Can you include what dependencies you're using?

Comment: i'm using a lot of .jar libraries of third party jar projects. if you want i can post them but you will not know what is inside these projects

Comment: This is usualy used when asking for somebodies identity things like email, phone number, name, last name, etc...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Why?

You are probably getting it [via some library that you are using](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html).

> What is this permission?

It is used, prior to Android 6.0, for using things like `AccountManager`.

> i can't find any official info about it on android developers guide!

That is because Google got rid of this permission in Android 6.0, and the documentation at http://developer.android.com does a really poor job of dealing with removed API elements.

Comment: can i remove that permission from my app with a safe result?

Comment: @AndroidUser99: I have no way to know. If you read the blog post that I linked to in the first paragraph of my answer, I outline your options for trying to get rid of it. But only the author of the library that is asking for the permission can tell you what you can and cannot do if you do not have that permission.

Comment: I got rid of USE_CREDENTIALS and my app crashed on a galaxy s5, even though I still had GET_ACCOUNTS and I'm compiling with target=23.. I suggest keeping these old permissions in your manifest.